# Making a route exception for a static file

Tags: angular2-routing

I've got some software out in the wild that needs to download some static file from a specific place on my domain: `domain.net/somefolder/setup.exe`. While I plan to change this, it's going to take a long time due to constraints out of my control.

In the meantime, how can I deal with this in my Angular2 router? Essentially, if Angular sees this specific url it should not try to resolve the url and instead serve the static file similar to how it would behave if you accessed static files from the assets folder.

`{ path: 'somefolder/setup.exe', ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing a url rewrite on the web server level within a config.